# Unicode different size arrows

Tags: html, css, unicode

I have the following code:

```css
.testFont {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outter">
    <div class="testFont">&#9652</div>
    <div class="testFont">&#9662</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The unicode table below shows that the arrows I used above should be equivalent in size (from visual inspection):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why are they rendered differently?
And how can I get equivalent arrow sizes?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xdrryne/)

### Update

Tested on Chrome and Safari both render the down arrow bigger?

### Output Image

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of *Lucida Grande* font, which might be the default font on your system :

[image][image]

To avoid it, define the font to use yourself (better a webfont so you'd be sure every one will see the same, but I don't know one that does support these glyphes).

```css
.testFont {
   font-size:16px;
   /* only tested on mac OS, 
      if someone could lead me to default win and *nix default fonts,
      I'd be glad to include it
   */
   font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS', 'Consolas';
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
   <div class="testFont">&#9652</div>
   <div class="testFont">&#9662</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kaiido thanks that worked for me. But out of interest I did set my font family in another example I did to the following: font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  but I still had the same issue. Does that mean that specific font family messed it up? I'm confused why this is happening?

Comment: @xenophon Apparently, *Helvetica* doesn't support these glyphes, nor does *Helvetica Neue*, *Arial* neither, but *Arial Unicode MS¨* does, *sans-serif* might default to *Lucida Grande* on your system. You can check which font on your mac Os  system supports which character in the right panel of the *Characters Table*, *Font Variation*. But once again, if you plan to face the web, use a web-font.

Comment: ok thanks you mean use a webfont just when trying to use these characters right?

Comment: Well not only. The best is to set a global web-font for everyone, then fallbacks to special characters only `body{font-family: myDefaultWebFont, mySpecialCharactersOne, Helvetica ... sans-serif}`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the arrows are the same size,  I think it is an optical illusion.   See fiddle with arrows output: https://jsfiddle.net/uv8yrrav/21/ I have not changed any of your code:

```
<body>
<div class="outter">
   <div class="testFont">&#9652</div>
   <div class="testFont">&#9662</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: LOL Chris It's no optical illusion the down arrow is definitely bigger

Comment: Let me add a fiddle

Comment: @xenophon my eyes must be terrible lmao could it be a browser thing?  What browser are you using, I am using chrome

Comment: Chrome on Mac Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

Comment: @xenophon,  they look exactly the same in my fiddle, are you referring to the background behind your arrow or the arrow itself?

Comment: no the the little arrow themselves are different let me post the image